Ошибка при создании обьекта SpeechRecognitionEngine
Нужно сделать программу, которая речь переводит в текст.
В интернете нашел, что можно использовать Microsoft Speech Platform. Сначала по ошибке скачал на x86 языковые пакеты, sdk и библиотеку, потом перекачал на x64. Не знаю помешало ли это работе программы, но вот такой код выдает ошибку при создании обьекта SpeechRecognitionEngine:
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Globalization;
SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("ru-ru"));
GrammarBuilder grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
grammarBuilder.Culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-ru");

ошибка на SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("ru-ru")); :
 System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Как решить эту проблему?

"ru-ru" заменить на "ru-RU"
